# Permissions problems with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I urgently need some advice as to why I have to change all files I want to edit to 777? I think there maybe sound thing wrong with the apache user not being the owner. I can only edit any file if I set 777 so anyone can edit it. Any help much appreciated.

cheers

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what's going on already.

Comment: but how could this have changed it's self? any pointer on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to.  Often this comes down to the group being incorrect.  My `wp-content` is owned by the user `apache` and the group `apache` on a standard Slackware Linux installation.

File permissions are 664 on these.  For me, I do:

```
chown -R apache.apache wp-content
chmod -R o-w wp-content
chmod -R gu+rw wp-content
```

Comment: do I need ssh access to run those commands or can I do it through cpanel? thanks

Comment: Maybe you can do it if cpanel provides an interface to set ownership or file permissions.  I don't know.  I doubt it'll let you execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

This web page on the wordpress.org website seems to be addressing your issue exactly: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/file-permissions-avoiding-777

This isn't really a thing that can be controlled from wordpress, but seems to have some relation to the way your hosting company configures its servers.